# Dictionaries and multi-item handling - GDScript

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm having trouble coming up with a system to organize bonuses from items collected over the course of a run. For example, the game 'Doomsday Hunters' (and any other rogue-like of the genre) has numerous items that add attributes and abilities to the player. How is this done?
I can imagine that all possible items to be collected in the game are in a database. However, does EVERY ITEM in that database contain all possible information with zero attribute (if the bonus is not relevant to that specific item)?

Therefore, the code linked to the player, must have a function that checks LINE BY LINE if the equipped item (present even in an Array or even an Inventory Dictionary - for example) if that specific item contains or not a certain property? I believe this is wrong and very time consuming.
I would like to learn how to do it.

Another cool example, the game 'Super Auto Pets'... has numerous items, with different properties, that can be equipped to selected allies. How would the code look like this?

Answer (score 1):

I will not implement it but I do have the following thoughts to this topic:

- I would not use a database right away, but if you decide on using one I would use the columns ItemID, ItemName. than add a table which has foreign key ItemID and than column attribute and column modifier (maybe even types for multiplier or adding/decreasing)
- than I would implement a function in the player which checks just the aqipped items and looks up their modifiers and attributes they modify (for example from the database or functions calls in the item itself)
- than the player could alter its own base values (which should never be changed in this example) with these collected modifiers.